# jQuery/css: selected amount of stars to light up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on making a star-voting system. There are 5 stars, those lighted up are showing the current average star voted. When you mouseover a star, lets say number 4 I wish to make the 4 from right lighten up, if you mark over 2, 2 stars should mark up from the right and so on.. if full 5 stars all stars lights up.
the stars are in css classes .iconFavorite and the lighten up is .iconFavorite_hover, so my code looks like this when 3:

```
<div class="iconFavorite_hover"></div>
<div class="iconFavorite_hover"></div>
<div class="iconFavorite_hover"></div>
<div class="iconFavorite"></div>
<div class="iconFavorite"></div>
```

If you check out [retardo.dk/videos.php?id=905](http://retardo.dk/videos.php?id=905)  you can see the big green stars try mouseover them, the selected amount of stars will light up.

How can I do this?

Here's a jsfiddle of my current code with no jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/8vzCC/1/

Comment: For anyone interested, [here's a pure CSS based solution](http://jsfiddle.net/H9Rn6/).  I was going to post it as an answer but Chrome and Safari have some issues with it (it only works if you move from left to right across the stars).  It works fine in IE7+, Opera and Firefox, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/8vzCC/33/
It removes everything after it :) This should work!

**EDIT:** New version, should work as you want it to work :)

Comment: please just edit your answer next time, yes it works almost on mouse out i want the default to show again (3 stars light) it doesnt it shows one if you chose one and go mouse out

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vzCC/3/) You will need a third class for "permanent" light up stars.

here is the jquery to make it work.

```
$(function() {
    $('.icon').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('iconFavorite_hover');
        $(this).prevAll('.icon').addClass('iconFavorite_hover');
    });
    $('.icon').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('iconFavorite_hover');
        $(this).prevAll('.icon').removeClass('iconFavorite_hover');
    });
});
```

To provide the extra functionality you are looking for I made some changes:
[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vzCC/45/) You can see there is a new class and extra hover changes.

Comment: thanks for you answer. there's only one issue. if you have 2 lighten stars from the beginning, http://jsfiddle.net/8vzCC/4/ , and you only want to rate 1 star only 1 star should light up. Right now it works only for the stars that are not lighten up

Comment: @Karem, I've added the extra functionality you needed. Give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you give all the div's an ID?
And then let jQuery do somthing like:
On hover --> this.id --> select every div with id lower or equal to 'this.id' --> set class="IconFavorite_Hover" ?

Comment: yes i can. Ok can you show me the code of the selector to select every div with id lower or equal to 'this.id' ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".iconFavorite").onmouseover(function(){

        $(this).prevAll(".iconFavorite").add(this).addClass(".iconFavorite-hover").removeClass(".iconFavorite");
        $(this).nextAll(".iconFavorite-hover").addClass(".iconFavorite").removeClass(".iconFavorite-hover");

}).onmouseout(function(){
    $(".iconFavorite-hover").addClass(".iconFavorite").removeClass(".iconFavorite-hover");
});
```

This removes the hover class from the next stars as well (so if they initially moused over the 4th star, and then went to the 2nd, the 3rd and 4th stars should not be highlighted